Understanding Oxidation States and Magnetic Moments in Multivalent Transition Metal Oxides
I’m reading some papers on using density functional theory (DFT) to study oxidation states in multivalent transition metal oxides, but I’m having difficulty interpreting the oxidation-state distribution from the results. According to suggestions on physics stack exchange, I repost the questions here. My background is in chemistry, so I may lack clarity in the physics behind this. I would appreciate any feedback on potential errors in my understanding.
After calculating a transition metal oxide with mixed oxidation states (e.g., LixMnO2 cathode material) using VASP in spin-polarized mode, Bader-charge analysis typically shows no significant difference in the local charges at transition metal centers, despite the metal being considered multivalent. Initially, I thought Zunger’s charge self-regulation concept could explain this—where ligand anions compensate for charge loss at the metal centers, suggesting oxidation states are not localized on the metal but rather dependent on the local chemical environment.
However, Ceder’s paper (in Fig. 1) suggests that by setting initial on-site magnetic moments for each transition metal atom, distinct on-site magnetic moments can be observed after electronic convergence, allowing oxidation states to be assigned based on these differences. This seems to contradict Zunger’s idea. Since spin is carried by electron, if charge self-regulation compensates for charge changes, why do on-site magnetic moments vary with oxidation state and not average out?
I have a question:
Is there any flaw in my understanding of these physical concepts? Could it be that charge compensation doesn’t affect magnetic moments?
Thank you for your insights!

+1 and welcome to our community! We hope to see much more of you in the future! Thanks for contributing your question here, I just edited it to comply with our one question per post policy!

Thanks @NikeDattani-NoFreeTime!
